# How do we obtain the divisor bound in similar but different settings?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

The divisor bound refers to the statement that the divisor function $d(n)$ defined to be the number of positive integral divisors of $n$, can be bounded very efficiently. Indeed, it is easily shown that $d(n) = O_\varepsilon \left(n^{\varepsilon}\right)$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$.

This, for example, immediately allows one to show that the equation $x^2 + y^2 = n$ has at most $O_\varepsilon \left(n^\varepsilon\right)$ solutions, since the solutions to this equation counts the number of divisors of $n$ over the Gaussian integers (which is a UFD).

Now consider the field $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ and the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$. We are in the nicest possible setting: $\mathcal{O}_K$ is monogenic, is a PID, and the unit group has rank one. Here my question can be made very explicit.

Suppose we want to factor a principal ideal of the shape $(s + \sqrt[3]{2} t)$, with $s,t$ coprime rational integers. We do so by writing

$$\displaystyle (s + \sqrt[3]{2} t) = R \cdot J$$

for ideals $R, J \subset \mathcal{O}_K$. Since $\mathcal{O}_K$ a is a PID, we can represent $R, J$ by $R = (r_0 + \sqrt[3]{2} r_1 + \sqrt[3]{4} r_2)$ and $J = (j_0 + \sqrt[3]{2} j_1 + \sqrt[3]{4} j_2)$ with $r_i, j_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ for $i = 0,1,2$. By fixing a fundamental domain of the action of $\mathcal{O}_K^\ast$ we can eliminate associates, and reduced to finding solution to an equation of the form

$$\displaystyle \begin{bmatrix} s \\ t \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} r_0 j_0 + 2 r_2 j_1 + 2 r_1 j_2 \\ r_1 j_0 + r_0 j_1 + 2 r_2 j_2 \\ r_2 j_0 + r_1 j_1 + r_0 j_2 \end{bmatrix}. (\ast)$$

By the divisor bound, we know that $I = (s + \sqrt[3]{2} t)$ has at most $O_\varepsilon \left(N(I)^{\varepsilon} \right)$ divisors, which immediately gives a good bound.

Is there a way to see this bound without using number theory? That is, for fixed $s,t$ can one show that $(\ast)$ has $O_\varepsilon \left((s^2 + t^2)^\varepsilon \right)$ solutions say, if we bound $|r_i|, |j_i|$ so that there can't be a unit group action? More generally, if we have three bilinear forms $Q_0(\mathbf{x}; \mathbf{y}), Q_1(\mathbf{x}; \mathbf{y}), Q_2(\mathbf{x}; \mathbf{y}) \in \mathbb{Z}[\mathbf{x}; \mathbf{y}]$ can we produce a divisor like bound for solutions $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}$ to the system

$$\displaystyle \begin{bmatrix} s \\ t \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} Q_0(\mathbf{x}; \mathbf{y}) \\  Q_1(\mathbf{x}; \mathbf{y}) \\ Q_2(\mathbf{x}; \mathbf{y})\end{bmatrix}$$

at least provided that $\lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert, \lVert \mathbf{y} \rVert \ll (s^2 + t^2)^{1/4}$?